# I know this isn't good, but what is it and how hard is it to replace?

Tags: chevrolet, part-identification, n-body

While replacing my brakes this weekend I saw this:

[image: Stabilizer bar?]

My best guess is that it is the stabilizer bar. It is attached further back in the frame or axle (can't remember for sure).

How hard would this be to replace it myself? It looks like just two bolts.

This is on a '98 Chevy Malibu.

Comment: Getting fixed today.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that is the sway bar. There are usually just a couple of bushings (one per side) that attach it to the frame and then however they connect it to the suspension. Shouldn't be hard to replace at all, though monkeying it around to get it in and out may be interesting.

Comment: I just stopped at the shop to have them take a look. They found a couple other things as well (I don't recall what off the top of my head). They'll fix it all for about $400. At this point, it's worth it for me. My time (and saved frustration) is worth more than they are charging in labor in this case.

Comment: Sometimes that's the best way to go.  My experience with GM swaybar bushings is that the bolts are really flimsy and snap right off.  Can be a lot of pain to work on compared to other makes.

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch, in fairness to the bushings and the bolts - it looks like they held.  The *bar* broke but the bolts appear fine....